# SizeToContent.Width and TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a grid with three differents controls, two are groupbox, and a third one is a treeview.
I don't know the initial width so the Window.SizeToContent is set to "Width"
Everything perfectly fits inside the window, the problem came when I extend a node from the TreeView, the Window.Width adjust to the new Width where the treeView fits perfect but the rest of the controls are not that nice.

I would like to keep the "original" width given by the SizeToContent, and get a ScrollBar when I extend the treeViewNode instead changing the whole Window.Width

Here is the xaml (just the main grid and the treeview)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Attachments-->
    <GroupBox x:Name="gbAttachments" Header="Attachments" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

        <TreeView x:Name="tvAttachments" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />

    </GroupBox>
    <!--Attachments-->
</Grid>
```

I have try with ColumnDefinition.Width = "*", HorizontalContentAlignment, and a lot of others differents ways, I have also tried to put it inside a ScrollbarViewer and nothing seems to work. Always when I extend the node, the whole window is extended with the content of the node (that it is actually quite long). I'm pretty sure that the problem is the Window.SizeToContent = 'Width' but what else I can do for the rest of the controls if I don't know the original width? Any Idead, Thanks in advance!

--EDIT

Well the solution was easier than expected, in the event Window_Loaded I get the gbAttachments.ActualWidth and assign it to the TreeView.MaxWidth
Not beatiful, pretty sure it can be done by xaml, but it is working.

Comment: I only see one groupbox - are there supposed to be 2 here?

Comment: Yes @Aaron, I just put the code for the treeview and the main Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the `MaxWidth` property of the nodes in your tree:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="80"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Alternatively, you can bind this value to something, such as another element for example:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
       Value="{Binding ElementName=gbAttachments, Path=ActualWidth}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Also, if you're concerned about not needing the window's autosizing to occur after it's initialized, you could try something in code behind so that the autosizing only happens on window initialization:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // auto-size width, and save off value
    this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Width;
    var actualWidth = this.ActualWidth;
    // manual-size width
    this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Manual;
    // set value to what it was, when auto-sized
    this.Width = actualWidth;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried all of your solutions but still the same, when I expand the TreeViewItem the whole windows width goes with it.

The solution on the code behind is even weirder because the ActualWidth is 0, I'm using MVVM maybe that is the reason it cannot get the actual width of all the controls inside, I don't know

Comment: Thanks for guide me to the solution:

The trick I did is on the Window_Loaded event, once it loaded the gbAttachments contains the ActualWidth initialized so I just got that one and assing to the maxWidth of the TreeView.